# How to remove default border of button in jquery mobile?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

How to remove default border of button in jquery mobile?
I declare the `<a>` tag as a button, with custom background images as below:

```
<a id="btnLogin" href="../main/mainx.html" data-role="button" data-corner="false"> Login</a>
<a id="btnSignUp" href="../singup/signup.html" data-role="button" data-corner="false"> Sign Up</a>
```

CSS:

```
a{
    width: 265px;
    height: 38px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 0px;
    border-color: transparent;
    display: box;
    text-transform: none;
    text-shadow: none;

}
#loginPage a .ui-btn-inner{
    padding-top: 11px;
}
#loginPage #btnLogin{
    background: transparent url(../../res/img/login_btn.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    color: #FFF;

}
#loginPage #btnLogin:hover{
    background: transparent url(../../res/img/login_btn_over.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#loginPage #btnSignUp{
    background: transparent url(../../res/img/signup_btn.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    color: grey;
}

#loginPage #btnSignUp:hover{
    background: transparent url(../../res/img/signup_btn_over.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    color: #fff;
}
```

The button shows within blur border like this: [image]

Please help me.

Comment: `.ui-btn { border: none !important; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to use button element, everything works fine.

```
<button id="btnLogin" href="../main/mainx.html" data-role="none" data-corner="false"> Login</button>
<button id="btnSignUp" href="../singup/signup.html" data-role="none" data-corner="false"> Sign Up</button>`
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you're looking for the [outline property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp) :

```
a {
    outline:0;
}
```

Comment: this helped me to remove it from the div#index, I used the following css   #index.ui-page.ui-page-active{ outline-color: transparent; }

Answer (score 3):

To override default styles for buttons in jQuery Mobile, do your modifications on class `.ui-btn` followed by `!important` for each property.

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/8TH5d/

```
.ui-btn { border: none !important; }
```

As for the shadow, add this attribute `data-shadow="false"` to `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the background image of button? it maybe contain border inside

Comment: The background images are ok. No outside border. I turn to use button element, It works.

Comment: you can try "outline:none" for "<a>".

Answer (score 0):

IMO best way to have back buttons is to do this

```
  $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {

        $.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
        $.fn.buttonMarkup.defaults.corners = false;
    });
```

However, $.fn.buttonMarkup.defaults.corners = false; doesnt remove round corners for back buttons that are automatically generated using the global options.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked fine for me

```
border: none !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
outline: 0;
```